# Formatted print to the console in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, methods, console-application

I have a method that returns a list of lists.

```
def get_ranking_matrix(self) -> list:
   return self.ranking_matrix
```

When I call `print(a.get_ranking_matrix())`, I get the classic output of a two-dimensional array:

```
[[2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5], [3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 2], [4, 1, 2, 6, 3, 5], [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3], [2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3]]
```

And if I call `print(a.get_ranking_matrix)`, then

```
 <bound method Ranking.get_ranking_matrix of <__main__.Ranking object at 0x000002431BB8F880>>
```

Can you tell me how to make a nice print, like in numpy. When you just write `print(some_dataframe)`

and get formatted table in the console:

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
A1   1   0   1   1   1   1
A2   1   1   1   1   1   1
A3   0   0   1   1   1   1
A4   0   0   0   1   1   0
A5   0   0   0   1   1   0
A6   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

How does this implement in practice?

I want to call this method inside `print(a.get_ranking_matrix)` and have the following in the console:

```
2 1 4 3 6 5
3 1 4 6 5 2
4 1 2 6 3 5
2 1 3 4 5 6
2 1 4 5 6 3
2 1 4 6 5 3
```

Comment: you need to implement a `__str__` method for your class...  https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__str__/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same output format manually like so:

```
def get_ranking_mat(the_list):
    my_str = ''
    for i in the_list:
        for elem in I:
            my_str+=str(elem)+ ' '
        my_str+='\n'
    return my_str 

print(get_ranking_mat(my_list))
```

you need to implement it within your class.

On another note, if your class `__str__` method is not used for other functionality I think That it is better to use it for printing the result.